# use libxml2 in android with JNI

Tags: android, c, java-native-interface, libxml2

I have created an app in android using `JNI`(as major part of my code is in C).Now i am having a requirement to parse `xml` in my application.since i have chosen `libxml2` for my application, can any one please tell me how to use `libxml2` in my android application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since there is no prebuilt libxml.so/.a file for libxml2 parser, so we need to create the library (either .so/.a) and use that in application, u have to download all the .c/.h/android.mk/Application.mk and just build the libxml library(either .so/.a)